# Python - can't convert to int

Tags: python

My entire code is below (didn't want to miss anything).  For some reason I keep getting an error where I can't convert a float to an int?

```
import math

def getRange(input):
    if (1 <= input < 10):
        return [1,1,9]
    elif (10 <= input < 190):
        return [2,10,99]
    elif (190 <= input < 2890):
        return [3,100,999]
    elif (2890 <= input < 38890):
        return [4,1000,9999]
    elif (38890 <= input < 488890):
        return [5,10000,99999]
    elif (488890 <= input < 5888889):
        return [6,100000,999999]

def getDigit(input):
    workingRange=getRange(input)
    multi_digit_dec = ((input-workingRange[1])/workingRange[0])+workingRange[1]
    multi_digit_float = math.floor((input-workingRange[1])/workingRange[0])+workingRange[1]
    print multi_digit_float
    multi_digit_int = input(multi_digit_float)
    decimal_remainder = multi_digit_int - multi_digit_dec
##    digit_id = decimal_remainder * len(str(multi_digit_int))
##    actual_digit = str(multi_digit_dec)[digit_id]
##    return actual_digit


getDigit(100)
```

My error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\Python\concatenate string of variables and product values.py", line 29, in <module>
    getDigit(100)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\Python\concatenate string of variables and product values.py", line 22, in getDigit
    multi_digit_int = int(multi_digit_float)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>>
```

**Code updated above to reflect change of variable called int to input**

Comment: Don't use `int` as a variable name, and your code will work fine.

Comment: Changed this but still no luck.

Comment: not possible, please post the edited code then.

Comment: As a note on style, your `if`/`elif` block can be simplified down to a dictionary (at the very least, you don't need the lower boundaries after the first as if it's below that value it will have been caught by the previous block).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I've updated the code in the original question.

Comment: @SamHeather `input` is also a built-in function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `int` as a variable name, and that shadows the [built-in function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int). Rename the variable.

In general, it's worth familiarizing oneself with the [names of the built-in functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html), to avoid this type of problems.

Comment: I've made this change throughout the code but it still returns that same error.

Comment: @SamHeather: The exception shows code (`int(multi_digit_float)`) that you say no longer appears in your code. Something's not quite right.

Comment: that is me converting the float to an int, not using 'int' as a variable name.  That's why that is still there.

Comment: @SamHeather: I am sorry, but that does not make a lot of sense. Your code and your exception are clearly out of sync. By the way, the `input(multi_digit_float)` you now have in your code should be `int(multi_digit_float)`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `int` as variable name (function `getDigit`).

Comment: An explanation as to why it causes the function to go wonky might help the OP

Comment: Darn it - thanks always forgetting these tiny things and they are so hard to find!

Comment: Hmm - it hasn't fixed it??

Answer (score 1):

In your stack of `elif` statements, if you start by testing if the input number is less than 1, then there's no need to check the lower ends of ranges other than the first.  This will cut out half of the verbiage in the `elif`'s.  Also, it is more compact to use a loop for tests like this.  For example, the following code produces the output shown below it.

```
def getRange(k):
    if k < 1: return None
    e = 1
    for d in [10, 190, 2890, 38890, 488890, 5888889]:
        if k<d:
            return [e, 10**(e-1), 10**e -1]
        e += 1
    return None

for i in range(14):
    print '{:8} {:20}'.format(i * 3**i, getRange(i * 3**i)),
    if i&1: print
```

Output:

```
       0 None                        3 [1, 1, 9]           
      18 [2, 10, 99]                81 [2, 10, 99]         
     324 [3, 100, 999]            1215 [3, 100, 999]       
    4374 [4, 1000, 9999]         15309 [4, 1000, 9999]     
   52488 [5, 10000, 99999]      177147 [5, 10000, 99999]   
  590490 [6, 100000, 999999]   1948617 [6, 100000, 999999] 
 6377292 None                 20726199 None
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
multi_digit_int = math.floor(multi_digit_float)
```

Also, don't use `int` as a variable name.

Comment: math.floor returns a float doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the line `multi_digit_int = input(multi_digit_float)` in your updated code is that the argument `input` in `def getDigit(input):` is hiding the built-in `input()` function. Since you calle `getDigit` with an argument of `100`, inside the function `input` is an `int` instance so the `input(multi_digit_float)` part is being interpreted as `100(multi_digit_float)`, i.e. an `int` calling something.